# hash function returns random value on the same input

Tags: c, hash

I am working on simple hash table of strings. I run program with the same input and in some cases hash returns a random number.

Here is my code:

```
LIST *table[1000];

void init()
{
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)   //set table to NULL
        table[i]=NULL;
}

 int hash(char *array)  //hash function         
    {
        int hash=0;
        hash=array[0]+strlen(array)+array[strlen(array-1)];
        hash=hash%1000;
        printf("%d\n",hash);    //print of hash               
        return hash;
    }

void add(char *arr)
{
    char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(arr)+1); //
    strcpy(str,arr);
    int h=0;
    h=hash(str);
    LIST *f=table[h];
    //...... rest of the code
}


int main()
{
  init();
  add("/");
  add("+");
  add("-");
  return 0;
}

And output is:
141
137
139
After rerun output is:
110
106
108
```

Does anyone know whats wrong with this hash function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess, `strlen(array-1)` is the culprit.

You don't know, what the character at `array - 1` is, and so it might sometimes return `0`. and sometimes it might return `strlen(array) + 1`.

As a consequence, you add `array[0]` to the hash value and sometimes you add one character beyond the string, `array[strlen(array) + 1]`.